# No version found for adamId - platform

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, tvos

I am trying to submit my tvOS application but keep receiving this message:

> No version found for 'adamId - platform' (XXXXXXXX-Apple TV OS). If
>   this problem persists for more than 24 hours, please contact your
>   Apple representative.

I've tried submitting the application using the application loader but the same message appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out a solution... or well it actually ended up just working... This is what I did:

Stepped away for about 24 hours and came back archived & submitted successfully.

I don't know why, but sometimes the best thing to do is just walk away and come back to it. (:
If you are trying to submit to application Loader, YOU MUST USE the one in Xcode because 3.0 is not valid for tvOS since it was created BEFORE tvOS.

Happy developing (:

Answer (score 1):

We run to the same issue.
The version was not created in the itunesconnect.
After we created the new version, we were able to upload the application